# Combine records and show in a different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have written a SQL which gives me a dataset.

```
    SELECT [Id]
      --,s1.[CustomerId]
      ,[Date]
      ,dc.ColumnName
      ,dc.ColumnId
      ,[RuleId]
     -- ,[RuleExceptionCount]
      --,[TotalRowCount]
      ,CAST((TotalRowCount - RuleExceptionCount)/CAST(TotalRowCount AS FLOAT) * 100 AS DECIMAL(6,2)) AS [FailurePercentage]
  FROM [ASMPredictiveAnalytics].[dbo].[DQHistory] AS s1
  JOIN dbo.DQColumns dc ON dc.ColumnId = s1.ColumnId
  WHERE Date = (SELECT MAX(date)  FROM
  dbo.DQHistory) AND s1.CustomerId=@CustomerId
```

The result looks like this

[image: Looks right now]

I wanted to result to look like this

[[image: Want to make it this way[2]]

Basically transpose the records for "Summary" and "Resolution notes" into a single record by adding another column called "Quality" and for the rest of the other "Columnnames", need to show the "Quality" as "N/A".

Comment: can you paste the results as formatted text as opposed to images. that will make it easier for people to copy your data and reproduce the issue and suggest answers. Better still create a runable script with a temp table containing the data and a query against it.

Comment: Do you need to put the values you have in `FailurePercentage` to `Quantity` column where `RuleId = 2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify your query like below:

```
SELECT 
     MIN([Id]) as [Id],
     [Date],
     [ColumnName],
     [ColumnId], 
     COALESCE(CAST(MIN(FailurePercentage) as varchar),'N/A') as FailurePercentage,
     COALESCE(cast(MIN(Quality) as varchar),'N/A') as Quality
 FROM
   (SELECT 
              [Id]
              --,s1.[CustomerId]
              ,[Date]
              ,ColumnName
              ,ColumnId
              -- ,[RuleExceptionCount]
              --,[TotalRowCount] 
              ,CASE WHEN [RuleId]=1 THEN CAST((TotalRowCount - RuleExceptionCount)/CAST(TotalRowCount AS FLOAT) * 100 AS DECIMAL(6,2)) ELSE NULL END as [FailurePercentage]
              ,CASE WHEN [RuleId]=2 THEN CAST((TotalRowCount - RuleExceptionCount)/CAST(TotalRowCount AS FLOAT) * 100 AS DECIMAL(6,2)) ELSE NULL END as [Quality] 
       FROM [ASMPredictiveAnalytics].[dbo].[DQHistory] AS s1
        JOIN dbo.DQColumns dc ON dc.ColumnId = s1.ColumnId
        WHERE Date = (SELECT MAX(date)  FROM
        dbo.DQHistory) AND s1.CustomerId=@CustomerId
    ) T
    GROUP BY [Date],[ColumnName],[ColumnId]
```

**Explanation:**

Since you were doing same calculations for failure percentage and Quality, I've put them as same inside the inner query, but one of them is NULL based on the value of `RuleId` column.

In outer query we've simply grouped everything and calculate the `MIN`(you can use any aggregate function here) not NULL value, and replace that value with `'N/A'` in case it is still `NULL`